# python polymorphism class and function

Tags: python

i am start to learn how to write python code

There is an option to write code ones onthis situation?
i want to crate class and 2 class how extend from her and i want to check if i can loop on only ones my example:

```
class animal:
    def printDetail(self):
       print(self.name)

class bird(animal):
    def printDetail(self):
       super(bird, self).printName()
       print(self.wingsSize)

class fish(animal):
    def printDetail(self):
       super(fish, self).printName()
       print(self.weight)

fishList = []
birdList = []
animalList = []

def main():
     for a in (animalList,fishList,birdList):
          a.printDetail()

main()
```

when i try to do it i got an error that AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'printDetail' like this is an unknow function. i understand that it try to take the attribute of the list class but there is any option that i can do it more esear then:

```
     for a in animalList:
          a.printDetail()
     for a in fishList:
          a.printDetail()
     for a in birdList:
          a.printDetail()
```

that is work fine but to long?

Comment: You can put everything into one list (for example, by joining the lists together); or you can use two loops - one to loop over `(animalList,fishList,birdList)` and the second to loop over the list that you get from that.

Comment: Just a side note to help with your learning. It is standard in python (see the python style guide at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to name classes with CapitalCase, so your classes would be named Animal, Bird, and Fish. I know that's a lot to think about when you are first getting started, but getting used to the standard will help a lot as you read other code, and help you develop consistency for yourself. Good luck with your Python learning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet creates a 3-tuple of lists. You're invoking `.printDetail()` on every list in that tuple.

To create a list that contains the elements from each list (as opposed to a list that contains the lists themselves), you can use `for a in (animalList + fishList + birdList):`

Answer (score 0):

As others have already answered, there are a variety of quick ways to do this. I prefer the unpacking method that Wups uses in his answer.

However, I also wanted to check if we needed to add initializations to each of these classes in order for the print to work. Further, I was thinking when you called printName in some methods, you meant printDetail instead (maybe I am wrong?). Thus I also revised the class code also, I hope it may benefit you and others who may want to run the code and see a result:

```
class animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
    def printDetail(self):
       print(self.name)

class bird(animal):
    def __init__(self, name, wingsSize):
        self.name=name
        self.wingsSize = wingsSize
    def printDetail(self):
       super(bird, self).printDetail()
       print(self.wingsSize)

class fish(animal):
    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        self.name=name
        self.weight=weight
    def printDetail(self):
       super(fish, self).printDetail()
       print(self.weight)

fishList = [fish("salmon",12)]
birdList = [bird("eagle",4)]
animalList = [animal("bear")]

def main():
     for a in (*animalList, *birdList, *fishList):
          a.printDetail()

main()
```

Output:

```
bear
eagle
4
salmon
12
```